# E a vector space and $T \in L(E), T(e_i)=e_{i+1}, T(e_n)=0$, $\exists S \in L(E) ; S^k=T$?

Tags: linear-algebra

There is a problem that has baffled my mind for a few days:

Let *E* be a n-dimensional vector space ($n\geqslant 2$); Linear transformation $T \in L(E)$ and basis ${e_1,e_2,...,e_n}$ for E exist such that $T(e_1)=e_2$, $T(e_2)=e_3$ , ... ,$T(e_{n-1})=e_n$ and $T(e_n)=0$.
Is there any $S \in L(E)$ for $k\in \mathbb{N}, k\geqslant2$ suchthat $S^k=T$?

Comment: What have you tried? What's a really simple case you could consider to work out what's going on?

Comment: @chappers Well I've tried setting $S$ as a transform that maps $e_i$ to $e_{i+j}$ and then applying number theory on it to form the $e_{i+1}$ for the $S^k$ but it didn't work, also I tried some cyclic functions in $\mathbb{R}$ and mapping it isomorphically to *E* and the same was the result!

Comment: Why not try $n=2$, see how that goes?

Comment: So you want to test $$\exists S \in L(E) \forall k \in \Bbb{N} \land k \ge 2, S^k = T.$$  Observe that $T^n = O$, so $S^{kn} = T^n = O$, but the quantifier for $k$ is $\forall$, this forces $T = O$, which is absurd.

Comment: @lulu it doesn't work, for $n=2$ it puts you in a crisis just as the same case crisis for arbitrary $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Or rather yes in the trivial case $n=1$, no if $n\ge2$. $S$ is nilpotent, so $S^n=0$. Now if $k\ge2$ there exists $m<n$ with $km\ge n$; hence $$T^m=S^{km}=0.$$But $T^m\ne0$ for $m<n$.

(Hmm, is it really true that if $k\ge2$ there exists $m<n$ with $km\ge n$? Sounds right... Ok, choose $m$ so $km\ge n$ and $k(m-1)<n$. Then $m<n$, because if $m\ge n$ then $k(m-1)\ge kn-k\ge 2n-2\ge n$ for $n\ge2$.)

**Edit:** Of course if $n=1$ then the conditions $T(e_1)=e_2$ and $T(e_n)=0$ are inconsistent. But in that case the first makes no sense, since there's no such thing as $e_2$; so I'm assuming that if $n=1$ the definition is $T=0$.